# Close browser from within browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I'm making a web browser touchscreen based application but I need to let the user close the web browser in order to shut the machine down after using, is there anything that can be done?

Using Windows, in either Chrome or Firefox

I've tried

```
browser.Close();
```

but this does not work in latest versions of browsers

please help, thank you

Comment: isn't `window.close()` instead of browser? Don't think you can close the whole browser.

Comment: Look at the electron framework, sounds like it would better meet your needs.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but as an avid internet browser user, I have never had an issue closing my browser using the red X in the corner, nor have I had an issue where I needed to press a button on a webpage so I could shutdown my machine. All sarcasm aside, @MrNew is correct that `window.close()` is what you need to close a webpage. (Of course, that's dependent on browser compliance, but nothing you can do about that.) However, without having elevated permissions (e.g., a web browser addon/extension), you cannot close the entire browser. You only have access/control over your own pages.